# Error When Connecting to MongoDB on Atlas Using Python3 and MongoAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongoalchemy

I am connecting to a cluster set up on MongoDB Atlas using the connection string given on the site.

I am running python3 and then run the import db from my module.

I get the error "pymongo.errors.InvalidURI: Invalid URI scheme: mongodb+srv"

My code looks like:

```
app.config["MONGOALCHEMY_DATABASE"] = "<CLUSTER NAME>"
app.config["MONGOALCHEMY_CONNECTION_STRING"] = "mongodb+srv://<REST OF URL GIVEN"
```

My install list looks as:

Package            Version

---

bcrypt             3.1.7
cffi               1.12.3 
Click              7.0
Flask              1.1.0
Flask-Bcrypt       0.7.1
Flask-Login        0.4.1
Flask-MongoAlchemy 0.7.2
Flask-PyMongo      0.5.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy   2.4.0
Flask-WTF          0.14.2 
itsdangerous       1.1.0
Jinja2             2.10.1 
MarkupSafe         1.1.1
MongoAlchemy       0.19
pip                19.1.1 
pkg-resources      0.0.0
pycparser          2.19
pymongo            2.8.1
setuptools         41.0.1 
six                1.12.0 
SQLAlchemy         1.3.5
Werkzeug           0.15.4 
wheel              0.33.4 
WTForms            2.2.1

Comment: Did you check the Atlas IP Whitelist to include your IP address? It's one of the most common problems while connecting to Atlas.

Comment: Yes it is whitelisted.

Comment: If I try connecting from the shell then I get first get an error about the port number so I append :27017 to the end and then I get the error below:

Comment: 2019-07-07T18:03:07.560+0100 Error: assertion src/mongo/client/dbclientinterface.h:231 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:148
exception: connect failed

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work now since I installed an earlier version with pip3 install Flask-MongoAlchemy==0.7.1

It now seems to connect, but I am running into other problems now.